# Update older branch without merging

Tags: git, merge, branch

I have a new branch for a release version and I did some changes there.
Now I would like to bring that changes into lagging master branch without merging the two branches.

Does this make any sense?
Should I have just used tags instead of branches?

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't making much sense.  What's the issue with merging?  Why is that a problem?  Have you thought about how the history of these two versions should tie together?  If you're simply trying to bring over a couple of commits, you could look at [`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) and pick the few commits you want to bring over.  Also, I don't see how tags vs. branches would have helped you here.  It's more about workflow and merge strategy.

Comment: I recommend you read up on the fundamentals of git, not just how to use it. Then you'll understand why what you're asking makes little sense.

Comment: I totally agree! As soon as I find some spare time, I'll dive into it...

Answer (score 2):

If you are just trying to put a commit from one branch on another, you can use a [cherry pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick).

This allows you to just apply a single commit from one branch to another without moving all the other changes over.

Move to the branch you want to cherry pick too, and then run:

```
git cherry-pick -x <commit-hash>
```

The `-x` will keep the commit message the same, and `commit-hash` is your commit's hash id.

Comment: FYI: `-x` doesn't keep the commit message the same, it appends a line saying what commit it was cherry-picked from.